# C Pigpio: read bit bang serial

Tags: c++, node.js, raspberry-pi, native, uart

I want to bit bang read from a UART Rx pin with C++ (actually developing a nodejs native module for this). I can successfully initialise the pigpio library, but when I try to read with this code:

```
gpioSerialReadOpen(TXD, 9600, 8);
while(true){ 
   gsr = gpioSerialRead(TXD, buf, 8);
   if(gsr < 0) {
      printf("%d\n", gsr);
   }else{
      fwrite(buf, 8, 1, stdout);
   }
   sleep(100);
}
```

I only get a 4-digit number read every time (the number is the same every application instance - when I restart the program, the number changes). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `buf`? It appears to be undefined.

Comment: Your code fragment is pretty useless - it’s incomplete so it can’t be compiled/run by anyone interested in helping you. 1. Create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of your problem - COMPLETE means someone could paste it into a file and compile/run it. MINIMAL means small - just enough code to show the problem. 2. Edit the code into your question.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind for the next time (see my answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed the problem, I forgot about setting the pin mode to input